# How to make a lazy loading high order component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

So here is the main idea, HOC that is be able to load any wrapped in component with React.lazy and React.Suspense. Is it possible???
So, I already was able to write some, but not sure that I was able to made properly...

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy, useState, useEffect } from "react"

export function withLazyImport(LazyComponent) {
  return (props) => {
    const [loadedComponent, setLoadedComponent] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
      setLoadedComponent(lazy(() => import(<LazyComponent {...props} />)))
      //eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    return (
      <Suspense fallback="Lazy component is loading ...">
        {loadedComponent}
      </Suspense>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using already existing solutions like [Loadable Components](https://loadable-components.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why do you use `useEffect`. The resulted component will not pass new props to the lazy component because props are passed on `did mount`.

I came up with another solution based on the example provided by the author of this question

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

export const withLazyComponent = (LazyComponent) => {
  return (props) => (
    <Suspense fallback="Lazy component is loading ...">
      <LazyComponent {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}
```

And then you use it like:

```
const LazyComponent = withLazyComponent(React.lazy(() => import('path/to/component')));
```

Comment: wonder if it would work with typescript..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to achieve it in **TypeScript**

```
import { Loader } from "../components/loader";
import { Suspense } from "react";

/**
 * HOC to wrap a component in a Suspense component.
 */

export default function withSuspense<P>(Component: React.ComponentType & any) {
  return function WithSuspense(props: P) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this also worked for me:

```
import { Suspense, FC, LazyExoticComponent } from "react";

function withLoadable<P extends object>(Component: LazyExoticComponent<FC>) {
  return function Loadable(props: P) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={"loading"}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
}

export default withLoadable;
```